# JavaScript: Guessing password

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

Another JavaScript question I found on the internet, but I couldn't figure out how it works. The question basically asks what is the password. The password doesn't depend on external resources and it doesn't change over time (do not depends on current date or time). Also, question says that there is exactly one correct password. I am JavaScript begginer, so I apologize if this is a simple standard interview question. This is the function:

```
const checkPassword = a => {
  if(a !== (a += '')) return false;
  if(a !== (a = a.replace(/[^a-z]/g, ''))) return false;
  a = (a.match(/^.{6}|.+/g) || []).join(({} + {})[7]);
  a = [...a].reverse().join([] + []);

  try{
    Function('\'' + a + '\';++1..a')();
    return false;
  }catch(a){
    return true;
  }
};

alert(checkPassword(prompt('Enter password:')) ? 'Correct password.' : 'Wrong. Try again.');
```

At first, this didn't look hard too me, because everything is open, so I can simply follow code line by line and figure out how does it work. Ok, I understand that in the first line of check function they check if password is a string (why? Can it be something else?). Then, if I understood that regex well, they check if script consists only of small alphabet letters (or am I wrong?). So, for now I know I know it must consists only of letters. After that they perform some weird regex I cannot fully understand. It seems to me that this regex will match whole string, so why they are joining it?

Then they reverse string and join by an empty array (is it same as normally reversing string or what?). After that in try block I cannot understand what is happening? What does `Function` constructor actually do here? What is the meaning of `++1..a`? Im just wondering how to approach questions like this one?

Comment: Hint: `({} + {})[7]` is a single space character, because `{} + {}` produces the *string* `"[object Object][object Object]"`.

Comment: Try stepping through the function with the debugger, or add a `console.log(a)` after each line. That line with `.match()` looks like it basically updates `a` to insert a space after the sixth character of the input.

Comment: @Bergi. Why did you remove ES6 tag? I don't think `[...a]` will compile in older ecmascripts.

Comment: @manga171 Only questions that are specifically about syntax from a specific spec version should be tagged with the respective tag. The [tag:javascript] tag is enough for generic ones. Your problem was about the regex and function constructor, not the spread syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll jump straight to the key line:

```
Function('\'' + a + '\';++1..a')();
```

It creates and then immediately executes a new function with a function body set from that weird-looking string. If the variable `a` is, say, `'abcde'` then the new function's body will be:

```
'\'' + 'abcde' + '\';++1..a'
```

which is like having this function:

```
function() {
  'abcde';++1..a
}
```

Or with some whitespace:

```
function() {
  'abcde';
  ++1..a
}
```

Note that the string on the first line is dynamically set based on what is in the `a` variable, but the `++1..a` part is hardcoded.

Now, noting that the function is inside a `try/catch()` block, if the new function runs without error then `checkPassword()` will return `false`, but if the new function crashes `checkPassword()` returns `true`. In other words, it is expected that the behaviour of that dynamic function will change to crash or not depending on what is in the string from the `a` variable.

So what string, by itself on the first line of a function, can possibly change the behaviour of the function? There is only one possibility, and that is (hover to reveal spoiler):

> `'use strict'` ...which would have to be entered as the password `'tcirtsesu'` because of the first few lines of the function doing the `.match()` and `.reverse()`.

With that in mind it doesn't even really matter what the `++1..a` part does, but it is basically taking the `.a` property of `1`, which is `undefined`, and trying to increment it, which...

> is an error in strict mode but not in non-strict mode.

For completeness, a very brief explanation of these lines:

```
a = (a.match(/^.{6}|.+/g) || []).join(({} + {})[7]);
a = [...a].reverse().join([] + []);
```

The `.match()` function returns an array. `/^.{6}|.+/g` matches the first six characters, OR any number of characters, which means that `"abcdefghijkl".match(/^.{6}|.+/g)` returns `["abcdef", "ghijkl"]`. Then `({} + {})[7]` is basically just a space character because `{} + {}` is the string `"[object Object][object Object]"`. So that line basically inserts a space after the sixth character.

The `.reverse()` line then reverses the result of that.